# Ping Succeeds From IIS Server, Not From Within Web App

Tags: iis, iis-6

I can successfully ping an external IP address from my IIS server when connected via terminal services from a command line.

However, when I set up my web application to do the same thing, the ping fails.  The site is running under the context of the anonymous account.

Are there permissions that I need to fix to get the ping to work within the web app?

Update: It does run successfully if I run the web app under the context of an admin account on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a permissions issue.  Are you able to easily configure your web app to use a user other an anonymous (even for testing purposes)?

Comment: Will try this now.

Comment: Yes, it worked when running under another account that has admin rights on the IIS machine.

Comment: Okay, so its a permissions issue.  You're going to have to run your web app as a user that has the appropriate permissions for what you want to do. :-)